# Function works in a session but not as Keras loss function

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am writing a custom loss function in keras.

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    c1 = (0.01 ** 2)
    c2 = (0.03 ** 2)

    y_true = tf.transpose(y_true, [0, 2, 3, 1])
    y_pred = tf.transpose(y_pred, [0, 2, 3, 1])

    patches_true = tf.extract_image_patches(y_true, [1, 8, 8, 1], [1, 8, 8, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], "SAME")
    patches_pred = tf.extract_image_patches(y_pred, [1, 8, 8, 1], [1, 8, 8, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], "SAME")

    # Get mean
    u_true = K.mean(patches_true, axis=-1)
    u_pred = K.mean(patches_pred, axis=-1)
    # Get variance
    var_true = K.var(patches_true, axis=-1)
    var_pred = K.var(patches_pred, axis=-1)
    # Get std dev
    std_true = K.sqrt(var_true)
    std_pred = K.sqrt(var_pred)
    covar_true_pred = std_pred * std_true

    ssim = (2 * u_true * u_pred + c1) * (2 * covar_true_pred + c2)
    denom = (K.square(u_true) + K.square(u_pred) + c1) * (var_pred + var_true + c2)
    ssim /= denom  

    return K.mean((1.0 - ssim) / 2.0)
```

Running it as follows:

```
test = tf.Variable(np.full((1,1, 32, 32), 10)/255.0)
test_1 = tf.concat([test, tf.Variable(np.full((1,1, 32, 32), 15)/255.0)], 0)
test_1 = tf.concat([test_1, tf.Variable(np.full((1,1, 32, 32), 20)/255.0)], 0)
test_1 = tf.cast(test_1, tf.float32)

test = tf.Variable(np.full((1,1, 32, 32), 30)/255.0)
test_2 = tf.concat([test, tf.Variable(np.full((1,1, 32, 32), 40)/255.0)], 0)
test_2 = tf.concat([test_2, tf.Variable(np.full((1,1, 32, 32), 50)/255.0)], 0)
test_2 = tf.cast(test_2, tf.float32)
test =  custom_loss(test_1, test_2)
init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op) #execute init_op
    print (sess.run(test))
```

works correctly, where test_1 and test_2 are test variables I created.

However, when I set that function as a custom loss for a Keras Model:

```
model.compile(optimizer=SGD(lr=0.01, momentum=0.9, decay=0.0, nesterov=False),
              loss=custom_loss, 
              metrics = ['mse', 'mae', PSNR, SSIM])
```

I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "kerasmodel_const_init_customloss.py", line 434, in <module>
    model.fit(x=[np.array(training_data_LR), np.array(training_data_MC)], y=[np.array(training_data_HR)], batch_size=128, epochs=2, verbose=1, validation_data=([np.array(validation_data_LR), np.array(validation_data_MC)], np.array(validation_data_HR)), shuffle=True, callbacks=[log_callback, checkpoint_callback])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/models.py", line 965, in fit
    validation_steps=validation_steps)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1646, in fit
    self._make_train_function()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 970, in _make_train_function
    loss=self.total_loss)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/optimizers.py", line 162, in get_updates
    grads = self.get_gradients(loss, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/optimizers.py", line 78, in get_gradients
    grads = K.gradients(loss, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2512, in gradients
    return tf.gradients(loss, variables, colocate_gradients_with_ops=True)
  File "/home/joe/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py", line 609, in gradients
    grad_scope, op, func_call, lambda: grad_fn(op, *out_grads))
  File "/home/joe/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py", line 375, in _MaybeCompile
    return grad_fn()  # Exit early
  File "/home/joe/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py", line 609, in <lambda>
    grad_scope, op, func_call, lambda: grad_fn(op, *out_grads))
  File "/home/joe/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_grad.py", line 733, in _ExtractImagePatchesGrad
    rows_out = int(ceil(rows_in / stride_r))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'long'
```

Is this some error in Keras or my bad? What is the problem?

Comment: You should show the piece of code where the problem occurs along with where the problem does not occur as you did

Comment: Hi ted, just updated the question. Baisically I just set it as the loss function to my model, as shown. Thanks

Comment: I see that the whole stacktrace is within Keras and TF, except for the first call. Did you check that all arguments to the `model.fit` call are correct? In particular, that all arrays contain reasonable data, and are of the right sizes?

Comment: Hi 9000. The model works correctly if I set the loss to one of Keras' loss functions. Furthermore, it does not return any errors when I use another function I wrote, which calculates the PSNR (currently being used as a metric)

Comment: @9000 , the stack trace might point to the `model.fit` function since it is the entry point, no?

Comment: Should I add the code for test_1 and test_2 tensors for easier replication?

Comment: Update: Added code for test tensors

Comment: @user3126802: Yes. The point is that it never _leaves_ TF / Keras functions, that is, the crash does not happen in `custom_loss`. Maybe `custom_loss` is fine, but something else is problematic.

Comment: @9000 I see. What's weird is that with other functions, it works correctly. The only change is in the loss function.

Comment: The problem lies in the fact that first dimension is equal to `None` in `keras`. You could try to set `batch_input_shape` instead of `shape` in a first / `Input` layer.

Comment: Hi @MarcinMożejko. What do you mean by `batch_input_shape`? Currently, my first layer is defined as follows: `model.add(Conv2D(filters=56, kernel_size=5, strides=(1,1), padding='same', data_format='channels_first', dilation_rate=(1,1), activation=None, use_bias=True, kernel_initializer='zeros', bias_initializer='he_normal',  kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.0), bias_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.0), input_shape=input_shape))`, where `input_shape = input_shape = (1,32,32)`

Comment: What is your `batch_size`?

Comment: Currently I'm working with batches of 128

Comment: `model.fit(x=[np.array(training_data_LR), np.array(training_data_MC)], y=[np.array(training_data_HR)], batch_size=128, epochs=1, verbose=1, validation_data=([np.array(validation_data_LR), np.array(validation_data_MC)], np.array(validation_data_HR)), shuffle=True, callbacks=[log_callback, checkpoint_callback])`

Comment: Try: `batch_input_shape = (32,) + input_shape`.

Comment: Where do I set that? in `model.fit()`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164999/discussion-between-marcin-mozejko-and-user3126802).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was really tricky. For some reason - a shape of an output tensor had an output of `(None, None, 1)` even though it might be computed from previous layers. Adding `Reshape(appropriate_size)` fixed an issue. This is probably an issue with `keras` which should be reported.